# Issue with Amazon Workmail – looking for POP/IMAP workaround

Tags: exchange, imap, amazon-web-services, pop3

We use **Amazon Workmail** for our email. I know it's a *preview* but it generally works well. Our company also picked up helpdesk software that needs to import email on the same domain using POP or IMAP. However, Workmail is **MAPI only** - there is no POP or IMAP access.

I thought that the solution could be to set up redirects in Workmail to mailboxes on a subdomain, with IMAP access.

However, Workmail refuses to redirect mail that originates from another domain because that technically means sending email from a non-authorised domain. I could use a forwarder but that would break the helpdesk software as it relies on the FROM field to identify users.

Moving to another email host is a last resort. I'm looking for a creative way to tackle this. Here are my ideas:

1. Set up the **IMAP mail server as the MX** and create an inbound relay using Postfix (we then lose most of the spam filtering advantages of Workmail)
2. Create a **third mail server**, with reliable spam filtering, to act as a relay for Workmail and the IMAP server and disable spam filtering on Workmail and the IMAP server.
3. Use a **forwarder in Workmail** and somehow make Postfix on the IMAP server rewrite the header and body of incoming mail before delivering it to the mailbox.
4. Find something that can **poll the Exchange server** every few minutes for new mail and deliver it to the IMAP server (I've not seen anything that can do Exchange -> IMAP but this would be ideal).

Please let me know if there are any other possible solutions to this conundrum!

Answer (score 0):

As of 2016-12-28, Amazon workmail now [supports IMAP](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2016/12/amazon-workmail-now-supports-a-wider-range-of-email-client-applications-including-microsoft-outlook-2016-for-mac-and-those-that-use-the-imap-protocol/).

You'll want to use one of the [IMAP endpoints](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#wm_region).

Currently, Amazon workmail does not support POP.